# How to get more detailed error information numpy for "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply" error

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

Is there a way to get more detailed from numpy for the error message

"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply"

It comes from a certain line in the code where I"m doing a number of array operations.  Can I get numpy to report:

(1) More information on the invalid value (inf? nan?)

(2) The array entry that is causing the problem?

Of course I can inspect the array myself but it would be nice if numpy could just tell me what  and where the problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably at least get more information on the type of error by [`numpy.seterrcall`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterrcall.html#numpy.seterrcall) (in conjunction with `numpy.seterr` as demonstrated in the link).  As far as figuring out which array is giving the problems, that probably isn't possible as `numpy` necessarily creates temporary arrays:

```
a = b + (c*d)
#       ^This creates a temporary array before adding it to `a`
```

Of course, you could use `seterr` to raise exceptions instead of warnings if you want to know what line number is the offending one in your code.

Comment: I used np.seterr(all='raise') to quit at that point in the code.